# How to add comments to the Test Reports shown on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We are using Test Report (Test Analyser plugin) for Jenkins to check for the failures.
But I am not able to add my comments, to the failed tests.
How can I do that. ? Is there any plugin ?

Or Is there any Report plugin which provides this facility.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I have added urgent to this as it is our client need. Not yet got any resolutions and I am working on only wayouts. Would really be greatful if get someting positive